# getline method only working once in nested loop

Tags: c++, input

I am trying to read from two files and compare both of them line by line with two loops. The first loop goes through the correct file line by line. The second loop prints everything in the other file all at once and compares every element in that file to the original.

My problem is that I am able to use getline(file, string) to read the lines in the second file in the first pass of the loop but am unable to see the values when i try and run the loop again. 
here is the code:

```
string userAttempts;
string correctNames;

ifstream nameFile;
nameFile.open("names.txt");

ifstream attemptsFile;
attemptsFile.open("attemptsFile.txt");

while (i < 25)
{
    j = 0;
    i++;
    getline(nameFile, correctNames);
    cout << "Outer: " << i << endl;

    while (j < 10)
    {
        j++;
        getline(attemptsFile, userAttempts);
        cout << userAttempts << endl;


    }
}
```

Output:

```
  Outer: 1
  Kid
  John
  Yes
  Time
  Yeet
  this
  hello
  Just Kidding
  Names
  Are
  Outer: 2
  empty
```

as you can see outer 2 is empty which is the second pass through the loop. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you point to the specific line of the program which seeks to the beginning of the 2nd file, so that it can be read again. Remember the Golden Rule Of Computer Programming: a computer only does what you tell it to do, instead of what you want it to do. Just because you want the inner loop to read from the beginning of the file each time is not sufficient. You must tell your computer that's what you want to do.

Comment: What are the contents of the files?

Comment: Please add contents of `names.txt` and `attemptsFile.txt` to your post.

Comment: What happens if there's less than 25 lines in the `nameFile` or less than 10 lines in the `attempsFile`?

Comment: 1) We definitely need to see the sample files.  2) Please explain what you're trying to do.  Do you want to (re)read the same 10 items from "attemptsFile.txt" each time in the inner loop?  If so, you can a) close and re-open the file each time, or b) use [rewind()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/rewind/)

Comment: This use of `while` is really irregular. Consider using a standard `for` for iteration.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is most likely that once you've read all the contents of `attemptsFile` then you have actually read all of it. The file won't automatically start reading from the beginning again.

If you want to do that you need to explicitly [seek](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg) back to the first position of the file again. Or why not define `attemptsFile` and open it inside the outer loop?

So the loops should looks something like this:

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < 25 && getline(nameFile, correctNames); ++i)
{
    ifstream attemptsFile("attemptsFile.txt")
    for (unsigned j = 0; j < 10 && getline(attemptsFile, userAttempts); ++j)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

---

If you want to read all of the contents of the files instead of a fixed number of lines, use e.g.

```
while (getline(nameFile, correctNames))
{
    // ...
}
```

instead.